I need to paste on x11 file
I need to write a program, which take a link to file and places it to clipboard. I've done it, but a can paste only in text strings in some messengers, like telegram. And there it pastes like file. But if i try to paste on desktop or file manager, nothing happens
void set_clipboard(xcb_connection_t *conn, xcb_window_t window, const char *file_path) {
    char uri[1024];
    snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), "file://%s", file_path);

    xcb_atom_t atom_clipboard =
        xcb_intern_atom_reply(conn, xcb_intern_atom(conn, 0, strlen("CLIPBOARD"), "CLIPBOARD"), NULL)->atom;

    xcb_atom_t atom_targets =
        xcb_intern_atom_reply(conn, xcb_intern_atom(conn, 0, strlen("TARGETS"), "TARGETS"), NULL)->atom;

    xcb_atom_t atom_text_uri_list =
        xcb_intern_atom_reply(conn, xcb_intern_atom(conn, 0, strlen("text/uri-list"), "text/uri-list"), NULL)
            ->atom;

    xcb_atom_t atom_mime_type =
        xcb_intern_atom_reply(
            conn, xcb_intern_atom(conn, 0, strlen("application/octet-stream"), "application/octet-stream"),
            NULL)
            ->atom;

    xcb_set_selection_owner(conn, window, atom_clipboard, XCB_CURRENT_TIME);

    xcb_flush(conn);

    xcb_generic_event_t *event;

    while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event(conn)) != NULL) {
        switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
            case XCB_SELECTION_REQUEST: {
                xcb_selection_request_event_t *req = (xcb_selection_request_event_t *)event;
                xcb_selection_notify_event_t notify_event = {.response_type = XCB_SELECTION_NOTIFY,
                                                             .requestor = req->requestor,
                                                             .selection = req->selection,
                                                             .target = req->target,
                                                             .time = req->time,
                                                             .property = XCB_NONE};

                if (req->target == atom_targets) {
                    xcb_atom_t targets[] = {atom_text_uri_list, atom_mime_type};
                    xcb_change_property(conn, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, req->requestor, req->property,
                                        XCB_ATOM_ATOM, 32, 2, targets);
                    notify_event.property = req->property;
                } else if (req->target == atom_text_uri_list) {
                    xcb_change_property(conn, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, req->requestor, req->property,
                                        atom_text_uri_list, 8, strlen(uri), uri);
                    notify_event.property = req->property;
                } else if (req->target == atom_mime_type) {
                    xcb_change_property(conn, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, req->requestor, req->property,
                                        atom_mime_type, 8, strlen(uri), uri);
                    notify_event.property = req->property;
                }

                xcb_send_event(conn, 0, req->requestor, 0, (const char *)&notify_event);
                xcb_flush(conn);
                break;
            }
        }
        free(event);
    }
}


Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a main() function and at least one #include. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

In the main function, the function written in the post is simply called

This function takes some arguments. "The function is simply called" does not reveal anything about these arguments. There must be a bit more ongoing in main before that function is called. Your code should be as complete as it needs to be to allow compiling it locally. If one hast to make up everything that is missing from your question, people might just walk away.

To extend what @Gerhardh said, if you write a "great question" (which means it's clear what the problem is, you don't omit important details, and is straightforward to reproduce) it's much more likely you will receive the help you need, and possibly an answer that solves it...

You've used the clipboard format "text/uri-list" to describe the file information in the clipboard. This format is already supported and understood by most software. However, in some (a portion, and so far I've only encountered file managers on various operating systems) software, they have their own special names for the clipboard content format for files. For example: "text/uri-list", "x-special/mate-copied-files", "x-special/gnome-copied-files", "text/x-moz-url".You can copy a file on the desktop or in the file manager, and then use xclip to view the list of clipboard formats in TARGETS.
